# Text chunked in 1080p in stupeflix task api

Tags: php, xml

i have an issue when generating a movie with the same xml definition : In low def no problem, but in high def, the main text is chunked.

Low def parameters  :

```
$postData = array(
    'api_key' => $this->access_key,
    'task_store' => array(
        'type' => 'volatile'
        ),
    'tasks' => array(
        'task_name' => 'video.create',
        'preview' => true,
        'definition' => $custom_definition
        )
);
```

Hight def parameters :

```
$postData = array(
    'api_key' => $this->access_key,
    'task_store' => array(
        'type' => 'youtube'
        ),
    'tasks' => array(
        'task_name' => 'video.create',
        'preview' => false,
        'profile' => '1080p-24-fps',
        'definition' => $custom_definition
        )
);
```

The xml used template :

```
<movie service="craftsman-1.0">
    <body>
        <stack duration="16">
            <audio filename="http://uri/ethnique.mp3" fadein="1" fadeout="1" duration=".."/>
            <sequence>
                <overlay duration="1">    
                    <image color="#000000" />
                </overlay>
                <transition type="crossfade" duration="1"></transition>
                <effect type="diving" duration="8" >
                    <image filename="http://uri/o_img.jpg"/>
                    <image filename="http://uri/img.jpg"/>
                    <image filename="http://uri/o_img.jpg"/>
                    <image filename="http://uri/img.jpg"/>
                </effect>
                <transition type="crossfade" duration="1"></transition>
                <stack duration="5">
                    <stack>
                        <effect type="none">
                            <image filename="http://uri/img.jpg"/>
                            <filter type="gaussianBlur" diameter="0.03" ></filter>
                        </effect>
                        <overlay>
                            <image color="#000000">
                                <filter type="radialGradient" color0="#ffffff" color1="#000000" point0="0.5,0.5" point1="1,1" ></filter>
                                <filter type="alpha" alphaStart="0.5" alphaEnd="0.5" ></filter>
                            </image>
                        </overlay>
                    </stack>
                    <overlay duration="..">
                        <text type="advanced" reference="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;" align="center" fontsize="17" fontcolor="#000000" face="arial">Passtime c'est jusqu'à 50% de réductions sur vos loisirs, commerces et restaurants dans tout le département !</text>
                        <animator type="grow" growEnd="0.2"/>
                        <animator type="custom">
                            <key time="0.0" pos="0,0.2,0"/>
                        </animator>
                    </overlay>
                </stack>
                <transition type="crossfade"></transition>
                <stack duration="5">
                    <!-- Affichage d'une logo rectangulaire -->
<overlay duration=".." width="1" height="1">    
                <image color="#ffffff" />
</overlay>
<overlay height="0.5" top="0.14" left="auto" right="auto" duration="..">
                <image filename="http://uri/img.jpg" />
</overlay>
<text type="zone" fontcolor="#000000" align="center,center" height="0.12" left="0.1" width="0.8" top="0.66" duration=".." fontname="arial">Message</text>
<text type="zone" fontcolor="#000000" align="center,center" height="0.12" left="0.1" width="0.8" top="0.74" duration=".." fontname="arial">Message</text>  
                </stack>
            </sequence>
            <!-- Mentions goes here -->

        </stack>  
    </body>
</movie>
```

Which is really wierd is that the sentence is chunked at `département !` which is replaced by `...`. And when I put some more text after that piece, like `département des bouches du rhone !` the chunked part is now `des bouches du rhone !`. More than that, if I remove the last space between `département` and `!`, everything goes well. This behaviour only happends in 1080p, even in the My Xeditor video.

Thanks for helping me out.